# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Control'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an array that has arrays within it.

The array is for a dynamic form, so when the user wants to add a new section it push's the array of control fields to the array, and it generates it in Angular2.

However I am getting this error:
`Error:(43, 41) TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

this is my code:

```
addDesign(){
    this.addForm.controls['design'].push(this.fb.group({
        name: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        a1: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        a2: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        a3: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        a4: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        a5: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        maxMark: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required)
    }));
}
```

My Constructor, initialising the form

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private auth: Auth, private authHttp: AuthHttp) {
        this.addForm = fb.group({
            name: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
            assignID: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
            design:  new ControlArray([])
        })
    }
```

I have tried doing `(<Control>this.addForm.controls['design']).push` as suggested in Angular2 issue 5871, but this has not solved it.

I am using TypeScript and Angular2 beta.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than casting to control, try casting to ControlArray (which should have push declared).

```
(<ControlArray>this.addForm.controls['design'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cAGjX.jpg check this image though it should be fine according to that diagram, and it does work, it push's onto the array, i forgot to mention that but the error is inteferring with my typescript compiler checking. I attempted addControl usage and it doesn't like handling arrays. Thanks though!

Comment: Okay. Try the cast you were doing before, but instead of `(<Control>this.addForm.controls['design'])` do `(<ControlArray>this.addForm.controls['design'])`

Comment: you legend! I dunno why I didn't think of that thanks alot! if you edit your main post I can then tick it as correct for others if they have same issue